# MySQL, utf8_general_ci & cyrillic characters

Tags: mysql

MySQL version 4.1 and its collation utf8_general_ci doesn't seem to like specific Cyrillic characters - 'с' and 'я'. Works in MySQL versions 5.0 and above.

Since the field is being used to store information in languages other than Russian (English, Estonian, German), changing the type of collation is unthinkable.

Has anyone had issues relating to that? Any thoughts (except upgrading MySQL)?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not like" exactly?

Comment: Try `mysql_query(mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');` when you run your queries. I've heard of this problem before, but I can't remember what the exact solution was.

Comment: Characters above are shown as '�?'.

Comment: This needs much more info for a decent answer. What are you doing exactly? Where is the data coming from, how is it entering the database? What platform or language are you using to get the data? How are you connecting to mySQL? What does the code look like? Where are you outputting the characters? What platform are you on? Can you show some code?

Comment: I'll try to describe the problem in detail then. On my webpage I have form that saves data into database. Now, when I retrieve those entries from database and try to show them on webpage, characters mentioned above are shown as '�?'. Webpage has encoding utf8, table and the field both have collation utf8_general_ci.

Comment: I had a quick answer, but it was based on PHP/MySQL stack. Pekka made a good point that we don't even know if you are using PHP. Please refer to Pekka's comment and provide further detail.

Comment: *How* does your webpage save data into the database? Using what programming language and what database library? (Edit: @Watermark beat me to the punch.)

Comment: Im using PHP, data is received with POST request and written into db with command mysql_query(). I dont think it has anything to do with PHP at all, because all the other characters are rendered correctly.

Comment: @WatermarkStudios "SET NAMES = 'utf8';" or "SET character_set_results=utf8;" causes all other characters being displayed faulty too.

Comment: What is the character set in your HTML header? It sounds like what you are writing to the DB isn't UTF8. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`?

Comment: Its UTF8. I'll give you an example: string "оборудование предприятий" is rendered (after being saved and then retrieved) as "оборудование предпри�?тий".

Comment: http://www.shawnolson.net/a/946/unicode_data_with_php_5_and_mysql_41.html

Comment: Glad to hear it! I just changed the answer to reflect the correct link. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.shawnolson.net/a/946/unicode_data_with_php_5_and_mysql_41.html

Comment: This answer could be improved by summarizing the important points of the linked resource.