# Query fails with Russian letters

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This query:

```
SELECT pair_ID FROM quotes_search WHERE  pair_type="type_one"
    AND ( symbol LIKE 'лукойл%' OR  UPPER(pair_name) LIKE UPPER('лукойл%') );
```

fails with Russian characters (English characters works fine).
Any ideas? table and field are utf8_general_ci

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
>       right syntax to use near ''
>   
>   One more thing, This query is successful when using mysql version:5.1.61
>   But failes when mysql version: 5.1.70

Comment: Are you running the query from the command line?

Comment: Slightly OT, but I suppose you are doing comparison with a nonbinary string, so case sensitivity does not matter and there is no need to use `UPPER` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: Maybe this can help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7780070/2186023

Comment: Even when removing the UPPER, I get the error

Comment: Are you sure it's the russian characters and not the double quotes around type_one?

Comment: Would adding an `N` or `_utf8` work? ie, `N'лукойл%'` or `_utf8'лукойл%'` It should specify that the string is an `nchar`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-national.html

Comment: @AsafMaoz yes that was OT = off topic just a suggestion for more efficient query ;)

Comment: From what I can tell it has something to do with the russian chars, if the string is: 'abc' it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run this queries after connecting db

```
SET character_set_client = "utf8";
SET character_set_results = "utf8";
SET character_set_connection = "utf8";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
... symbol LIKE CONCAT(_utf8 x'лукойл%', '%') OR ...
```