# HTML Website Character Encoding Mess

Tags: php, html, encoding

I am supposed to create website for customer with content in Slovak language (that means it contains special characters
  like č, č, ó, ď, ť and so).I'm using MySQL database with data encoding `utf8_general_ci`. This data is fetched by PHP 
  which generates HTML code and fills it with this textual data recieved from database. I used:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
  in head of generated HTML,

modified php.ini using steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website),

in php script itself called `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`. Result is that all special characters are
  displayed like questionmarks.

Is there any finite list of steps to do to secure that everything will be displayed properly?

EDIT:

As I found solution already, I would like to share steps that helped me to handle UTF-8 website, if anybody struggles too.

1.) Change php.ini using steps mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605760/how-to-best-configure-php-to-handle-a-utf-8-website) article's best answer.

2.) In the beginning of responsible php script call  `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

3.) Before executing any query, call `mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES utf8");` (I call it once on the top of the script right after setting up `$con` connection).

4.) Place `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in head of your HTML code.

5.) Change your database's collation to any utf8 type (I use `utf8_general_ci` as I mentioned).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you tryed charset windows-1250? Sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779978/mysql-utf8-general-ci-cyrillic-characters)

1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is UTF-8
2. On the page you insert these russian characters ( the form, textarea ), make sure the encoding is UTF-8, by setting Content-Type to `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Enter in russian text directly to the form input.
3. On the processing page that handles this form, which inserts it into the database, make sure to do `SET NAMES utf8` so it's stored as UTF-8 **before** you insert the data, in a separate query beforehand.
4. When you render the content from the database in a view, make sure the `Content-Type` is `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Make sure that the content-type is **not** windows-1251 or iso-8859-1/latin1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is NOT ISO-8859-1/Latin1.

Comment: Those are Slovak, not Russian. But SET NAMES saved me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data is properly encoded as UTF8 — query it with an UTF8 capable terminal/application and confirm you can see the accented characters properly. If not, you'll need to check your input forms for properly setting the data encoding. Use `<form accept-charset="utf-8">` but don't rely on it — check and convert if necessary at the backend.

Also make sure all your files are also encoded as UTF8: php files, templates, javascript, html widgets.